# Python TKinter videoplayer with a playlist

Tags: python, tkinter, video-player

I'm a novice in programming, as you can easily tell. But I was especially intrigued by my attempt to create a video player with the TK module that can play a list of videos.
The curious part is that I got some different results without receiving an error message.
The code that seemed most functional was this one. There are no execution or syntax errors. But I can only play the first and last video in the list.
Can anyone identify how to fix this?

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo
import os

origem = "C:\Python\Estudos\Videos"
lista=[]
for i,j,k in os.walk(origem):
    for arquivos in k:
        lista.append(arquivos)

playlist = iter(lista)
def load_v(video):
    videoplayer.load(video)


def play_v():
    videoplayer.play()

def play_next_video(event, videoplayer, playlist):
    next_video = next(playlist, None)
    print('Next is:', next_video)
    if not next_video:
        return
    load_v(next_video)
    play_v()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=root, scaled=True)
    videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    playlist = iter(lista)
    video = str(lista[0])
    load_v(video)
    play_v()
    videoplayer.bind("<<Ended>>", functools.partial(play_next_video, videoplayer=videoplayer, playlist=playlist))
    root.mainloop()
```

I just wanted a video player capable of reading files from a specific folder and playing them in full screen.

Comment: Unsure, but `play_next_video` logic seems okay. You wrote`playlist = iter(lista)` 2 times. Can you verify that the list of videos from os.walk contains all the videos you want?

Comment: Does it print out all of the video files when `print('Next is:', next_video)` runs? Have you tried printing out `lista` to check what it contains?

Comment: The list received all the items. The prints appear. The files were read and loaded, but unfortunately only the first one is displayed, followed by the last one listed. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am a Windows 10 user.
Your code looks good overall.

The problem seems to have occurred simply because when Python's next() function is first called, it returns the first item and moves on to the next.

Therefore, it works if you delete `playlist = iter(lista)` declared in the middle and change `video = str(lista[0])` to `video = next(playlist, None)` when playing the first video.
It would be a good idea to edit the path part as well.

So the full code is...

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo
import os

origem = "C:\Python\Estudos\Videos"
lista=[]
for i,j,k in os.walk(origem):
    for arquivos in k:
        lista.append(os.path.join(i, arquivos))

def load_v(video):
    videoplayer.load(video)


def play_v():
    videoplayer.play()

def play_next_video(event, videoplayer, playlist):
    next_video = next(playlist, None)
    print('Next is:', next_video)
    if not next_video:
        return
    load_v(next_video)
    play_v()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=root, scaled=True)
    videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    playlist = iter(lista)
    video = next(playlist, None)
    load_v(video)
    play_v()
    videoplayer.bind("<<Ended>>", functools.partial(play_next_video, videoplayer=videoplayer, playlist=playlist))
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I agree with the changes. Mainly the duplicated iteration. It was a lapse of attention. But unfortunately the result is still the same as what I got... Any other suggestions?

Comment: I did a test with 5 mp4 files and they all played fine.

Comment: It didn't work for me and I can't understand why! :(